# SSD RAID Controller, 6Gbps bandwidth limit for the whole controller or per SSD

Tags: ssd, raid

We are looking to buy raid controllers and 4 SSD's in raid10 on it, will the raid controller be a bottleneck of this setup?

Comment: The answer to this question is in the specifications for the controller itself.  One must remember that to the system a RAID is a single device so the 6Gbps limit isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the controller.

The RAID controller will have its own bottleneck based off of its controller and the interface it uses.

For example, over PCI the RAID controller will likely have the bandwidth of PCI. Although the controller may be less capable than the interface.